# Save Json objects inside mysql column database don't work

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

Actually i work to save json objects inside column that has a json as type,

when i reveice  a $request i do json_encode to all the $request object , the problem is , when i try to persist the objet , that's not work because the json_encode generate double cout "" in the begin and in the last of the new object like this

`"{"1505779480":{"numero":"8445546451","lastname":"belfkih","firstname":"thamer","profession":"psychnoterapeute"}}"`

mysql don't accept this objet because  of the double cout as you see in this line, i don't have any solution to fix that.

by the way i think it's a issue inside MySqlGrammar laravel class !!

Comment: please define that json into variable and save in database with field which has long text or text data type

Comment: Check if your MySQL version is **MySQL 5.7.8** or higher. [Docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json.html).

Comment: I find the solution, I just implement the serialization of laravel modal. below the link to laravel doc to do this: [link of solution](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-serialization#serializing-to-json)